# Do we need to shutdown ExecutorService fixedThreadPool

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have created threadpool using `ExecutorService`, in my application to call vendor websrvice, using below code.

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(getThreadPoolSize());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    Request ecpReq = list.get(i);           
                    thRespLst.add(executor.submit(new Task(ecpReq)));
                }
```

Wanted to know do we need to take care of shutting down threadpool or something, basically I don't want hanging threads in production environment.

Comment: Javadoc says: "An unused `ExecutorService` should be shut down to allow reclamation of its resources."

Comment: Your iterating is not thread-safe: calling `list.size()` may return a  number `N` and right after that, before you call `list.get(i)` the `Nth` element may have been deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **newFixedThreadPool**

> public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
>
> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads
>   will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
>   when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
>   thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during
>   execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed
>   to execute subsequent tasks. **The threads in the pool will exist until
>   it is explicitly shutdown**.

Javadocs.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122987/reason-for-calling-shutdown-on-executorservice) a good explanation.

Answer (score -2):

`FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` override `finalize()` to do the shutdown.

```
/**
* Invokes {@code shutdown} when this executor is no longer
* referenced and it has no threads.
*/
protected void finalize() {
    shutdown();
}
```

Acutally, I see no reason to explicitly shutdown the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: ExecutorService must be shutdown explicitly to reclaim the resources (CPU & Memory) occupied by threads which have already finished their job but still exist.