# Is it necessary to shutdown an ExecutorService for a webapplication running in a Tomcat container?

Tags: java, tomcat, executorservice

Is it necessary to shutdown an `ExecutorService` at some point if it runs in a Tomcat container for a Servlet. If yes, then where should I call the shutdown? I tried adding it after the submit() call but when I fire another request to the Servlet from a client browser, I get a `RejectedExecutionException` which is probably because I did a shutdown? I am trying to understand how it works in a Servlet within Tomcat and how I should use it.

I am doing the following in my webApplication (which seems to work fine without any shutdown):

```
// In configuration class
@Bean (name = "executorService")
public ExecutorService executorService() {
  return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);
}

// In some other class
@Qualifier("executorService")
@Autowired
private ExecutorService executorService;
....
private void load() {
  executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomethingInTheBackground();
    }
});

// If I enable this I will get a RejectedExecutionException 
// for a next request.
// executorService.shutdown();
```

}

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703865/do-we-need-to-shutdown-executorservice-fixedthreadpool

Comment: @Marvin I have read the comments in the link thanks. But where should I Call shutdown because it throws an exception for consecutive requests. And what would happen if I just don't shutdown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea behind the `ExecutorService` is to reuse threads. Creating threads is expensive and usually it is more efficient to create a thread once and then use that same thread multiple times. This is exactly what an `ExecutorService` does: it manages a pool of (possibly idle) threads and assigns work to them when you call its `submit` methods.

In a typical application you therefore do not want to shutdown the `ExecutorService`. You should however shut the `ExecutorService` down properly if your application is terminated. Since you are using Spring you don't have to worry about that:

> By default, beans defined using Java config that have a public close or shutdown method are automatically enlisted with a destruction callback. [See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-lifecycle-callbacks).]

That means, if you close the `ApplicationContext`, Spring will automatically shutdown the `ExecutorService` for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. The fact that Spring manages the shutdown was the missing piece I was looking for.