# Shutdown java ExecutorService using javax.annotation.PreDestroy in GCP CloudRun

Tags: multithreading, google-cloud-run

My SpringBoot App is deployed on CloudRun in GCP.
I have a class in java which returns static ExecutorService, say the following:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

public class MyExecutorServiceManager {
    private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    // Private constructor to prevent instantiation
    private MyExecutorServiceManager() {}

    // Method to get the static ExecutorService instance
    public static ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
        return executorService;
    }

    // Method to shut down the ExecutorService
    @PreDestroy
    public static void shutdownExecutorService() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I need to understand that:

- Once the REST service(s) consuming the above class have stopped executing all tasks, the ExecutorService instance being static will continue to exist and will stop CloudRun container will continue to run and never shutdown.

OR

- When a Cloud Run container instance receives a request, it is initialized and serves that request. If there are no incoming requests for a certain period of time (typically a few minutes), and there are no background tasks or threads actively running in the container, the platform may scale the container down to zero instances to conserve resources. When this happens, the container is stopped, and any cleanup tasks like shutting down the ExecutorService are invoked before shutdown owing to the @PreDestroy in above class.

Used @PreDestroy annotation to shutdown the ExecutorService, but NOT sure if the shutdown is being invoked or NOT

Answer (score 0):

When a Cloud Run service is not processing any request, it will become [idle](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#idle). The idle time is 15 minutes then will enter the [shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#instance-shutdown) phase.

Do note that:

- In using the annotation [@PreDestroy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html#:%7E:text=The%20method%20on%20which%20PreDestroy,method%20MUST%20NOT%20be%20static.), the method must **NOT** be static. So in your case, the shutdown might not be executed.
- Take a look at this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122987/reason-for-calling-shutdown-on-executorservice) to better understand how to shutdown ExecutorService